# Scaled Image actor in Table Layout doesn't expand cell

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Sorry for the dense title :)

Say I have an Image Actor created like so:

```
Image image = new Image(texture);
image.setScale(2);
```

adding it to a Table works, and shows properly, but the scaling of the image doesn't expand the size of the table.

```
table.add(image);
table.add(anotherimage);
//these images are now overlapping because 'image' is too large for its cell
```

Is this a known issue, and is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Try to set the width and the height of the Image

Comment: did you try? This does not work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the width/height of the image's cell so that it fits properly in the table.

Comment: actually, I just had to set the width and height of the image's cell. If you want to update your answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
table.add(image).fill().expand();
```

fill() is for the image to fill the cell.

expand() is for the cell to expand over the available space.